# CLLocationManager not very accurate inital updates

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

This is stated in CLLocationManager class reference:

> > When requesting high-accuracy location data, the initial event delivered by the location service may not have the accuracy you requested.

This is really affecting my app. How can I make sure that the location found is the one with the correct accuracy?

I tried to use the 4th or 5th update rather than first retrieved location but this is not a good solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the accuracy of the updates, [`CLLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocation)
contains a property [`horizontalAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW18) which you can use to check the accuracy.
When the `CLLocation` has an accuracy that you find accurate enough you use and ignore al others.

Als you should tel [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) your desired accuracy. To do this set the [`desiredAccuracy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW18) property in [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I read about this solution somewhere else and I will try this soon although I don't how it calculates an unknown location accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to live with that. That's how Apple implemented it. Getting a fine grained position takes time, just think about how long any windshield-mounted GPS devices in cars take to fix up their position.

So instead of letting your application wait for a longer time, they provide with what accuracy is available almost immediately, based on cell-towers and WiFi hotspots in the vicinity. Only when there has been a more reliable GPS fix will they call into your app again and let you know.

In the end, it is just a question of where the waiting for the fine-grained position is: In your app, where you have the chance of doing something with the more coarse-grained data you get quickly, or in their framework with no chance for apps to do anything useful in the meantime. I think, letting you decide is the better choice.

Depending on the type of app, you could have a map that automatically zooms in deeper as soon as better position data comes in, draw a smaller circle around the position you are expecting etc. For the end user, nothing's worse than waiting without getting any feedback. So even though this is probably not the answer you would have liked, I advise to make the best of it from a user's perspective.

Comment: I agree that enforcing waiting time to the user is crazy. But the problem is, my app just needs a location and does not need any more update. There's nothing to be shown on the map. It just get a location and finds nearest bus stop and it's worthless if you have a bus stop within 100m but first couple of location updates will give you a bus stop somewhere in the next neighborhood.